# When i reopen my project the design is totally blank

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I've recently started using android studio. When I reopen my project the design is totally blank and component tree shows nothing to show. Even after this app is running perfectly fine when I run it in my smartphone. [Render problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ8eU.png)
[String index out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIHBv.png)

Comment: Try to fix the 2 errors mentioned in the screenshot or elaborate them

Comment: Both are in the screenshot. 1)Render problem 2)String index out of range

Comment: Can you expand them and add image to see details completely

Comment: i have added error images.

Comment: Don't post only image. Post also error text and Your code.

Comment: Post your layout file code

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click on the highlighted area to see what's wrong.

```
select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart'
```

Comment: it is shown in picture. Render problem and string index out of range. I tried to solve render problem in youtube but nothing works:(

Comment: open the message and try to solve if it is a real issue, otherwise sometimes studio have some sync issue  just Invalid cache and restart should solve the problem